# Does nature have more than four dimensions?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

1. Does nature have more than four spacetime dimensions?
2. If so, what is their size?
3. Are dimensions a fundamental property of the universe or an emergent result of other physical laws?
4. Can we experimentally observe evidence of higher spatial dimensions?

Comment: All your questions are open problems in physics. We dont know the answer (yet?).

Answer (score -2):

Obviously nature has more than four dimentional coordinate system. It may be of any size. Yes dimension should be fundamental. No... But it is theoritacally possible that there are more than four dimensions... Here is the difference between physical structure​s from mathematical structeres. Thank you....

Comment: Yeah I feel stupid asking that question now